# Font doesn't load correctly when running from jar

Tags: java, fonts, awt

I have a problem with Java. I load a new font using this code:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.PLAIN, getClass().getResourceAsStream("/some/packages/fonts/font.ttf")));
```

When I debug it in NetBeans, everything works correctly, here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl3dT.png

[image: correct font]

But, once I compile my game font doesn't load (or at least doesn't display correctly), like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h73TS.png

[image: wrong font]

And there's one more thing - when I run jar from Terminal (java -jar app.jar) - font works! I have no idea why and how to fix it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: DYM the 'PLAYER 1' text?  It looks like the same font, a little larger and less bold.

Comment: What does getResourceAsStream return?

Comment: Well, it's definitely not te same font. Font I want to use is so bold by default, take a look: http://www.dafont.com/upheaval-pro.font

Comment: getResourceAsStream returns: java.io.BufferedInputStream@6639c8c1
There is no error or exception.

Comment: BTW - how big is the font file, and can you upload it somewhere we can hot-link to it?  Also a tip:  Add @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen (or whoever - the `@` is important) to ensure they are *notified* of a new comment.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Font file is 301kB, I uploaded it to my server: http://xayan.pl/UpheavalPro.ttf

Comment: Yes.. I noted that comment the first time you made it, after surfing around to see several other fonts that looked and called themselves the same thing came in at around 40-50Kb.  That is when I closed the page showing your latest comment in disgust.    40-50Kb is what I consider small enough to be workable, but I am not about to run code that hot-links to a font adding up to 1/3 megabyte.

Comment: Did you find out the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you say that the app runs correctly when running a command, then try this:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar app.jar");
// make sure to provide path for it
InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();
InputStream err = proc.getErrorStream();
OutputStream out = proc.getOutputStream();
// in/out/err streams of proc
```

Answer (score 0):

I may find the problem. First of all, do you pack the true type font file with the jar? It should be in side the jar or same with the current directory.

sorry for I cannot explain clearly, here are some examples of the font file location:

situation 1:

```
%cd%/some/packages/fonts/font.ttf
%cd%/your.jar
```

situation 2:

```
url of your.jar: file:///C:/some/your.jar
url of font.ttf: jar:file:///C:/some/your.jar/!some/packages/fonts/font.ttf
```